# Composing actors

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I've implemented a Listenable/Listener trait that can be added to Actors. I'm wondering if it's possible to attach this style of trait to an actor without it having to explicitly call the *listenerHandler* method?

Also I was expecting to find this functionality in the Akka library. Am I missing something or is there some reason that Akka would not not include this?

```
trait Listenable { this: Actor =>
    private var listeners: List[Actor] = Nil

    protected def listenerHandler: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
        case AddListener(who) => listeners = who :: listeners
    }

    protected def notifyListeners(event: Any) = {
        listeners.foreach(_.send(event))
    }
}

class SomeActor extends Actor with Listenable
{
    def receive = listenerHandler orElse {
        case Start => notifyListeners(Started())
        case Stop => notifyListeners(Stopped())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not extend `Actor` directly, or if you want non-Actors to be Listenable also, create a ListenableActor that extends Actor with Listenable?

You then would override `receive` in Actor as you've done above (except you'd want to call `super.receive` also, wouldn't you?--you'd just want to modify the function that's passed in).

Comment: Well this is the thing, in both situations I would have to remember to call either super.receive or *listenerHanlder*. I was wondering if there was a mechanism in Scala in general or any of the Actor libraries that allowed the actor implementing Listenable to not have to do anything except say: *with Listenable*

Comment: But you'd only have to say `extends ListenableActor` instead of `extends Actor`; inside `ListenableActor` you'd have already overridden `receive` (and, presumably, `receiveWithin`).  See also Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you extend Actor and use an `abstract override`.

Answer (score 2):

Why haven't I seen this question before, erm, well, better late than never:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (a modified version of the example from Beginning Scala):

```
import se.scalablesolutions.akka.actor.Actor

case class AddListener(who: Actor)
case class RemoveListener(who: Actor)

class ListenableActor extends Actor {
    private var listeners: List[Actor] = Nil

    def receive = {
        case AddListener(who) => listeners ::= who
        case RemoveListener(who) => listeners.filter(_ ne who)
    }

    protected def notifyListeners(event: Any) = {
        listeners.foreach(_.send(event))
    }
}

class ImplementingActor extends ListenableActor {
    override def receive = {
        super.receive orElse {
            case Message(content) => println(content)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in support for this in Akka: https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/release-1.2/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Listeners.scala